# Name of a book - Genius Space Squid Defeats bad guy, I *think* the word "Emperor" is in the title

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, humor

The "squid" was emperor of a planet and had, at one time, been a "super villain". It's all set in space and has many references to gadgetry. Humorous sci-fi book and I can't recall the name.

Comment: Sorry found it. It's an A.Lee Martinez book, Emperor Mollusk Versus the Sinister Brain

Comment: Please post that as an answer (along with details of why it is the answer). You won't be able to accept it for another two days or so, but it will help other people looking for the same book.

Answer (score 3):

Per the OP's comment above, this book is [Emperor Mollusk Versus the Sinister Brain](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1374835), by A. Lee Martinez, publish 2012. The [book summary at goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10979852-emperor-mollusk-versus-the-sinister-brain) gives an overview of the plot:

> Emperor Mollusk.
>
> Intergalactic Menace. Destroyer of Worlds. Conqueror of Other Worlds.
> Mad Genius. Ex-Warlord of Earth.
>
> Not bad for a guy without a spine.
>
> But what's a villain to do after he's done . . . everything. With no
> new ambitions, he's happy to pitch in and solve the energy crisis or
> repel alien invaders should the need arise, but if he had his way,
> he'd prefer to be left alone to explore the boundaries of dangerous
> science. Just as a hobby, of course.
>
> Retirement isn't easy though. If the boredom doesn't get him, there's
> always the Venusians. Or the Saturnites. Or the Mercurials. Or . . .
> well, you get the idea. If that wasn't bad enough, there's also the
> assassins of a legendary death cult and an up-and-coming megalomaniac
> (as brilliant as he is bodiless) who have marked Emperor for their own
> nefarious purposes. But Mollusk isn't about to let the Earth slip out
> of his own tentacles and into the less capable clutches of another. So
> it's time to dust off the old death ray and come out of retirement.
> Except this time, he's not out to rule the world. He's out to save it
> from the peril of THE SINISTER BRAIN!

Comment: Sounds like this is taken from the book's blurb. It's great fun. Very inventive, ingenuous, and amusing. Martinez is wonderfully funny. Comparable to Terry Pratchett or Douglas Adams in the humour department.